# Substrings and splitting

Tags: ruby, string

I have a lot of messages formatted like this

```
"42[\"message\",\"base64:QWZ0ZXIgQnVuZGxlciBpbnN0YWxscyB0aGUgZ2VtcyBpbiB5b3VyIEdlbWZpbGUsIHlvdSBjYW4gcHJvY2VlZCB0byByZWZlcmVuY2UgdGhlbSBpbiA0eTQ0NG91ciBjb2RlIGp1c3QgYXMgaWYgeW914oCZZCBpbnN0YWxsZWQgdGhlbSB5b3Vyc2VsZi4=\"]"
```

What I want to do is if the message contains base64: then extract the substring after the colon and before the next quote mark.

edit: this works but is probably horrible.

```
if event.data.include? 'base64:'
    new_string = event.data[event.data.rindex("base64:") + "base64:".length..-3]
    puts new_string
end
```

Comment: What is stopping you? What have you tried so far? Show us your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message = "42[\"message\",\"base64:QWZ0ZXIgQnVuZGxlciBpbnN0YWxscyB0aGUgZ2VtcyBpbiB5b3VyIEdlbWZpbGUsIHlvdSBjYW4gcHJvY2VlZCB0byByZWZlcmVuY2UgdGhlbSBpbiA0eTQ0NG91ciBjb2RlIGp1c3QgYXMgaWYgeW914oCZZCBpbnN0YWxsZWQgdGhlbSB5b3Vyc2VsZi4=\"]"
base64 = message[/base64:(.+?)"/, 1]
puts(Base64.decode64(base64)) unless base64.nil?
```